# How to update single embedded document in nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

How to update single embedded document inside an document in nodejs and mongoose

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have document in User collection like this :

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   address: {
              street: "123 Fake Street",
              city: "Faketon",
              state: "MA",
              zip: "12345"
            }
}
```

you want to update subdocument address

```
var UserModel = require('path-to-user-mongoose-model-here');

UserModel.updateOne({_id:"joe"},
                    {$set:{
                           "address.street":"My Updated Street", 
                           "address.city":"My City",
                           "address.state":"NY",
                           "address.zip":"11332"
                         }
                    });
```